# Change the address of the music player if not available

Tags: plugins, php

```
$mp3Linkger = wp_get_attachment_url($mp3_file_id);

$mp3Link = wp_get_attachment_url($mp3_file_id);
$mp3Link = str_replace( 'example.COM', 'static.example.COM', $mp3Link );

    $playerTag = '[audio mp3="'.$mp3Linkger.'"][/audio]';
```

In the above code

```
$playerTag   loads the link
$mp3Linkger  Is broadcast
```

**I want to load $mp3Link  if  $mp3Linkger was not available**

Not available like Down Server or 404 error and ...

Comment: You need to test the "headers" of the URL to see if the code returned is what you want - here are some answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408405/easy-way-to-test-a-url-for-404-in-php

Comment: Doing this will mean a heavy/expensive check that will not be reliable. Down for you doesn't mean down for me, so a HTTP check can never be reliable. On top of that, even if it is available, the situation you're trying to avoid isn't avoidable because if you decide server side then the computer at the other end fails to load the MP3 despite it being available, it'll be broken. ***There is no PHP based solution to this, it must be done in javascript***, which means the `audio` shortcode cannot be used for this as there is no way to pass the second URL to it

Comment: as an aside, your `static` subdomain means that you will have reduced/slower performance on HTTP2 connections. Static CDN subdomains only improve performance on HTTP1.0 when using older browsers, browsers made within the last few years are not optimised this way and will see a performance loss, not a performance gain, my recommendation is to abandon it, and avoid this problem completely by always using `$mp3Linkger`